# Different depths between objects

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, depth

I made a game on two objects. Background and main character. However i want some of the elements of background to be above character. Changing depth of elements to bigger than player's depth doesn't work.
Help please. Is there any way I could avoid making background in two objects?

Comment: not likely. if you want elements about your character (which I asume is foreground), by definition it would not be part of the background, it would need to sit on a 3rd depth on top of everything, right ?

Comment: Put the elements that you want above the player on a different layer (assuming that you're using layers).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to swap depths between different movieclip you have to create all the elements on the same parent.
You should not place your elements in the flash IDE layers.

For example :

```
myGameMC.attachMovie("#myBackground","myBackground",1);
myGameMC.attachMovie("#myCharacter","myCharacter",2);
myGameMC.attachMovie("#myForegroundElement","myForegroundElement",3);
```

Then you can swap the depths of the elements

```
myGameMC.myCharacter.swapDepths(myGameMC.myCharacter.myForegroundElement);
```

or

```
myGameMC.myCharacter.swapDepths(3);
```

or

```
myGameMC.myCharacter.swapDepths(myGameMC.getNextHighestDepth());
```

Hope that it help you.